# Using php to get a tags id and output result

Tags: php, html

Im stuck trying to make PHP output the content within a set tag id.

Example: `<div id="myID" class="section">...Content to output...</div>`

But i only manage to make PHP output from the tag.

Example: `<div>...Content...</div>`

Here is the code ive used:

```
    $theTag = $_REQUEST['tag'];
$url = $_REQUEST['url'];
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$output = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);


$DOM = new DOMDocument;
$DOM->loadHTML( $output);

//get all H1
$items = $DOM->getElementsByTagName("$theTag");

//display all H1 text
 for ($i = 0; $i < $items->length; $i++)
        echo $items->item($i)->nodeValue . "<br/>";
```

I would use a query similiar to `http://example.com/get-content?url=http://example.com/page.file&tag=myID`

How can i make this work ?
Thanks!